# Purpose of Index in Mongoose Schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to add unique documents in the collection. However the problem is I want to decide uniqueness based on 2 fields. So I found a solution for it online. What confuses me is, What is the purpose of`INDEX` here? In RDBMS index is usually the word used for row id, what does this mean here and how does it affect the uniqueness?

```
var patientSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name : String,
  fatherOrHusbandName : String,
  address : String,
});


patientSchema .***index***({ email: 1, sweepstakes_id: 1 }, { unique: true });
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It actually has the same purpose like indexes in RDBMS. You just have to think in some mongo-terminology. In mongodb instead of Tables, you have collections, instead of rows, you have documents.
With mongoose you defined a schema for a collection 'Patient', within this collection(**index belongs to Patient collection**) you defined a `unique index` on the document properties `email` and `sweepstakes_id`.

Every time you save a document in the Patient collection, mongodb makes sure that a document which has the email and `sweepstakes_id` properties set, those 2 properties will be unique among all other documents.

So, instead of 'rows', think in 'documents'

Comment: I still don't understand the purpose of index here... Can you please elaborate the index idea in mongoose?

Comment: Ok, to be more specific: Indexing is a core mongodb functionality, mongoose just helps you to define it nicely among your schema definitions (which are not mongodb core, mongo has no schema). In the end it creates an index on your collection like described here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/indexes/. You can achieve the same just creating an index directly on the mongo database

Comment: What you try to achieve is described here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/, and the type of Index you are creating is called Unique Compound Index. So if you compare the way you do it directly on the database and in mongoose, the operation how you define looks almost same:  
mongodb: db.<your_collection_name>.createIndex( { email: 1, sweepstakes_id: 1 }, { unique: true })  
mongoose: patientSchema .index({ email: 1, sweepstakes_id: 1 }, { unique: true });  

This helps ?

Comment: Ok so to sum up the explaination, index is the caching here. Like Windows indexes files to be fetched quickly. Right?

Comment: Yes, instead of traversing the whole documents, mongo saves an index separate for fast access, for ex. here to check if there are already same values existing if a new document is inserted. Indexing in general has the same idea behind it

Comment: so in my particular case, the index has 2 values that'll later be used to detect the unqueness of the new data. Right?

Answer (score 19):

> Indexes support the efficient execution of queries in MongoDB. Without
>   indexes, MongoDB must perform a collection scan, i.e. scan every
>   document in a collection, to select those documents that match the
>   query statement. If an appropriate index exists for a query, MongoDB
>   can use the index to limit the number of documents it must inspect.

for more details see [this documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/indexes/) .

Don't be confused after reading this document because this document uses `createIndex` and you're code uses `index`. `createIndex` is for **MongoDB** and `index` is for **mongoose** that internally executes MongoDB operations.

If you have no data in your database then it will work fine

```
patientSchema .index({ email: 1, sweepstakes_id: 1 }, { unique: true });
```

but if you have some data in the database with duplicate items then you should use `dropDups` keyword to make it a unique index.

But one thing you should know before use `dropDups`. If you use `dropDups: true` and you have some data with duplicate value then keep one document in your database and all the other data will be **deleted** (duplicate data).

Like:

```
patientSchema .index({ email: 1, sweepstakes_id: 1 }, { unique: true, dropDups: true });
```